# Mapping Custom Named/Native Queries to Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

It's possible mapping custom native/named queries to entities? I have something like this

```
NamedQueries({
    NamedQuery(name = "StateBo.findByCountry", query = "SELECT state FROM StateBo state WHERE state.country.id = ?"),
    NamedQuery(name = "StateBo.showIdfindByCountry", query = "SELECT state.id FROM StateBo state WHERE state.country.id = ?")
})
@Table(name = "STATE")
@Entity(name = "StateBo")
public class StateBo extends BaseNamedBo {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3687061742742506831L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STATE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ISO_CODE")
    private String isoCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private CountryBo country;

   // getters and setters ...
}
```

I have my method to call Native/Named queries like this.

```
@Override
public List<E> executeQuery(String queryName, List<Object> criteria) {
TypedQuery<E> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName, entityClass);
Integer argumentPosition = 1;
if ( (criteria != null) && (criteria.size() > 0) ){
  for(Object object : criteria) {
    query.setParameter(argumentPosition, object);
    argumentPosition++;
  }
}
return (List<E>) query.getResultList();
}
```

When I call the **StateBo.findByCountry** the result is mapped to **StateBo**, but if I call **StateBo.showIdfindByCountry** the result is not mapped to **StateBo** because I'm only selected on the query the *state.id* instead of the fields on the table.

I don't want to select all the fields of the **STATE** table, I only want in this case the **state.id**, but when I customize my native query, the result is not mapped to **StateBo** instead of this, the result is a Long type.

My question is, Is possible map to an Entity the result of **StateBo.showIdfindByCountry**? I case that I have more fields like state.isoCode, is possible map to StateBo, the custom query? or only is possible if I return all the fields from the query, like the first query **StateBo.findByCountry**

Comment: Don't even think about doing that. You and your collegues will suffer from such a design decision. If a method returns StateBo instances, the caller expects to get actual, attached StateBo instances. Not detached StateBo instances where all the fields are null and all the invariants broken because it only contains an ID. A method returning IDs should return a `List<Long>`. A method returning ID/code pairs should return a `List<StateIdAndCode>`. Note returning 2 out of 3 fields of an entity won't lead to any significant performance advantage over returning the entities themselves.

Comment: Also: you keep using the term native query, but your queries are not native. Native queries are queries written in SQL instead of JPQL.

Comment: Thanks, @JBNizet my principal doubt is, if return some fields instead all fields, helps in the performance or is the same performance on both cases?

Comment: *Note that returning 2 out of 3 fields of an entity won't lead to any significant performance advantage over returning the entities themselves.*

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but as JB Nizet said - "your collegues will suffer from such a design decision".

Anyway, in order to do that you should create custom constructor in your entity class. This constructor should accept `Long` argument and assign it to `id` field of your entity class.

Then you should change your query to include `NEW` keyword followed by full qualified entity class name as below:

```
SELECT NEW your.package.StateBo(sb.id)
FROM StateBo sb
WHERE state.country.id = ?
```

Please note that all entities retreived from database in such a way will not be managed by persistence context.